# Integral with variable change

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

How do I go about solving this

[image]

I put $x=t-\frac{1}{t}$ but I'm not able to proceed ahead .

Comment: The answer is 1.

Comment: @velutluna It is , but how ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will use two alternative methods to show that 
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x) \, dx = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f \left (x - \frac{1}{x} \right ) \, dx.$$

---

**Method 1**

$$I = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f \left (x - \frac{1}{x} \right ) \, dx = \int_{-\infty}^0 f \left (x - \frac{1}{x} \right ) \, dx + \int_0^\infty f \left (x - \frac{1}{x} \right ) \, dx. \tag1$$
Enforcing a substitution of $x \mapsto -1/x$ in the above integral yields
$$I = \int_0^\infty f \left (x - \frac{1}{x} \right ) \frac{dx}{x^2} + \int_{-\infty}^0 f \left (x - \frac{1}{x} \right ) \frac{dx}{x^2}. \tag2$$
Adding (1) to (2) gives
\begin{align*}
I &= \frac{1}{2} \int_0^\infty f \left (x - \frac{1}{x} \right ) \left (1 + \frac{1}{x^2} \right ) \, dx + \frac{1}{2} \int^0_{-\infty} f \left (x - \frac{1}{x} \right ) \left (1 + \frac{1}{x^2} \right ) \, dx.
\end{align*}

Now let $u = x - \frac{1}{x}, du = (1 + \frac{1}{x^2}) \, dx$, gives
$$I = \frac{1}{2} \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(u) \, du + \frac{1}{2} \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(u) \, du,$$
or
$$ \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x) \, dx = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f \left (x - \frac{1}{x} \right ) \, dx,$$
as required.

---

**Method 2**

$$I = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f \left (x - \frac{1}{x} \right ) \, dx = \int_{-\infty}^0 f \left (x - \frac{1}{x} \right ) \, dx + \int_0^\infty f \left (x - \frac{1}{x} \right ) \, dx.$$
In the first integral appearing on the right, let $x = -e^{-u}$. In the second let $x = e^u$. Thus
\begin{align*}
I &= \int_{-\infty}^\infty f \left (-e^{-u} + \frac{1}{e^{-u}} \right ) e^{-u} \, du + \int_{-\infty}^\infty f \left (e^u - \frac{1}{e^u} \right ) e^u \, du\\
&= \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(e^u - e^{-u})(e^u + e^{-u}) \, du\\
&= \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(2 \sinh u) \cdot 2 \cosh u \, du.
\end{align*}
Now if we let $x = 2 \sinh u, dx = 2 \cosh u \, du$, giving
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty f \left (x - \frac{1}{x} \right ) \, dx = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x) \, dx,$$
as before.

Comment: In the first method , how did you get the intution of putting x as -1/x ?

Comment: Also , can you upvote the question ? Some jerk did it after our argument in the chat

Comment: Notice that using a substitution of $x \mapsto -1/x$ leaves the argument of $f$ unchanged so is worth a try before making the "obvious" substitution of $u = x - \frac{1}{x}$.

Comment: okay , would you kindly check this as well ? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2664316/limit-with-double-derivative-and-modulus

Answer (score 2):

Let
$$u=x-\frac{1}{x}$$
Then
$$x=\frac{u\pm\sqrt{u^2+4}}{2}$$

The integral becomes
$$\int_{-\infty}^0f(x-\frac{1}{x})dx+\int_0^\infty f(x-\frac{1}{x})dx$$
$$=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(u)d\frac{u-\sqrt{u^2+4}}{2}+\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(u)d\frac{u+\sqrt{u^2+4}}{2}$$
$$=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(u)d(u)=1$$

Comment: In case anyone's curious, this result is called Glasser's master theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glasser%27s_master_theorem

Comment: @vlutluna Why did you split it at $x=0$ and then how did you write the next line ?

Comment: @Tanuj The idea is to transform each half-line in an order-preserving or order-reversing way.

Comment: @Tanuj Plotting $u$ versus $x$ may help.

Comment: @velutluna I'm still not getting how you got $$=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(u)d\frac{u-\sqrt{u^2+4}}{2}+\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(u)d\frac{u+\sqrt{u^2+4}}{2}$$

Comment: @Tanuj When $x\to -\infty$, $u\to -\infty$, when $x\to 0^-$, $u\to \infty$, when $x\to 0^+$, $u\to -\infty$, when $x\to \infty$, $u\to \infty$.

Comment: @velutluna oh does u still not go to -infinity when x tends to 0 ?

Comment: @Tanuj Yes, when $x\to 0^+$.

Comment: @velutluna can you come here https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73591/integral