# Limit with double derivative and modulus

Tags: limits, continuity

[image]

Inspite of knowing a thing or two about limits , this particular question just completely stumps me . What does it want me to do and how do I operate with the modulus ? Taking double derivative of $x^p \sin(\frac{1}{x})+x|x^3|$ also seems too complicated.How do I approach this ?

Comment: Hint: $x|x^3|=x^3|x|$ is just a distraction. As for $x^p\sin(1/x)$ use taylor expansion of $\sin$.

Comment: @user251257 What do you mean by distraction ?

Comment: it is twice continuously differentiable and does not depend on $p$